# Stopping a Python Multiprocessing BaseManager 'serve_forever' server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following setup in Python 3.6 for interprocess communication:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class MyManager(BaseManager): pass
MyManager.register('get_instance', callable=lambda:my_instance)
m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'key')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

To avoid blocking my message loop of a larger application, I used a thread to contain this setup. So `s.serve_forever()` actually runs inside a `run` function of a thread.

This is done according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). And the setup itself worked fine with client managers calling into the shared instance.

However, I found no way to stop this 'serve_forever' server. Since the documentation didn't mention this, I checked the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py). There's a `stop_event` which supposedly I can `set` to quit the loop. But it didn't work, as the `accepter` daemon/thread is still running. And I can't call `shutdown` on the server object because I don't have the socket object `c`.

So how do I shut down this server?

ps. Using `BaseManager.start()` isn't really an option for me because the server in my case shares an async message loop which can only be accessed by the starting process. `BaseManager.start()` spawns a new process which no longer has access to the message loop. `get_server().serve_forever()` on the other hand, runs within the calling process.

Comment: The name implies that it will run forever. When do you want to shut it down? When exiting your program, or at a time of your convenience?

Comment: Also, have you tried running `serve_forever()` in your main application? It will create a thread to run in automatically. Are you sure it will block your message loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the server:

```
import threading

s = m.get_server()
stop_timer = threading.Timer(1, lambda:s.stop_event.set())
MyManager.register('stop', callable=lambda:stop_timer.start())
s.serve_forever()
```

And in the client:

```
MyManager.register('stop')
m.stop()
```

UPDATE:

I solved the timeout issue by delaying the `stop_event.set()` with a `threading.Timer`

OLD:

However, across machines, you then run into long timeouts as the `stop()` method fails to receive data, this answer talks about that - but I could not get it work:

[properly disconnect multiprocessing remote manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512884/properly-disconnect-multiprocessing-remote-manager)

I'm new to the multiprocessing managers, I will update this answer if I find a better solution. (UPDATE: Found, updated)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack after reading the `multiprocessing.managers` source, stripped from `_finalize_manager()`, basically creating a connection to the server and send a shutdown msg

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import dispatch,listener_client

_Client = listener_client['pickle'][1]
# address and authkey same as when started the manager
conn = _Client(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey=b'key')
dispatch(conn, None, 'shutdown')
conn.close()
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I've spent hours on this with no clue why the regular SyncManager.shutdown() function doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap/use the manager start/shutdown to avoid this running forever server (start() starts a server for you):

```
m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'key')
m.start()
# do something
m.shutdown()
```